# Url Rewrite for angular urls

Tags: angularjs, url-rewriting

I have Angular URL e.g "www.mycompany.com/employee/{78}" .
I want to rewrite this url as if i click on this employee and try to open it in new tab its using base url i.e. "www.mycompany.com/index.html/employee/78".

```
 <rule name="main rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^index.html/employee/[0-9]+$" /> 
                    <action type="Redirect" url="/employee/{78}" appendQueryString="true" />
 </rule>
```

Here my question is how i can use the querystring ?? i.e. in this case employee id while rewriting the URL. Right now i have put the constant 78 but instaed of any constant i want to refer to "[0-9]+$" this value.

Answer (score 0):

Found following answer. Need to put parenthesis for ([0-9]+) to use {R:1}.

```
<rule name="main rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^index.htm/employee/([0-9]+)" /> 
     <action type="Redirect" url="/employee/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```